# What‘s the difference between ant's property value and property location

Tags: java, ant, compilation

Ant's config file--build.xml has the property element.
And according to the offical-doc,the property has the attributes-value and location.
But I don't understand why we need location?
Can I set the path as a value in property? Then no need for location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

location is used if you want to do relative paths.

notice in this example, they use location.  no absolute path needed.
http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

either location or value (mutually exclusive) can be used if you're doing absolute paths

Comment: I seem to know something,if I use the location, I can't use the value,vice versa.If I need to define a path, using value will oblige me to give a full path.Using location, there's no need to give a absolute path.Is it right?

Comment: that is correct.  btw, it's useful to use echoproperties if you want to debug if your properties are correct.  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html

Answer (score 2):

Sets the property to the absolute filename of the given file. If the value of this attribute is an absolute path, it is left unchanged (with / and \ characters converted to the current platforms conventions). Otherwise it is taken as a path relative to the project's basedir and expanded.

Source : http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

Example, someone want to store lib dir path in a variable then it can be done as shown below.

```
<property name="lib.dir" location ="project_home/lib"/>
```

and you can use the above property as shown below.

```
<fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>.
```

Comment: still don't understand. Your example shows that we can use 'value' instead of 'location'.