# Ant build fails not expanding out environment variables

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I have a problem with the build process on a new server that I have setup just for development purposes.

This is running on a Centos 6 box with Java/Tomcat v7. The output is as follows:

```
Buildfile: /home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/build.xml

init:
     [echo] Build of EES started at 1332 on December 19 2015

clean:
     [echo] Cleaning EES
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/build

compile:
     [echo] Compiling EES
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/build/WEB-INF/classes
    [javac] Compiling 78 source files to /home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/build/WEB-INF/classes

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/build.xml:118: /home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/${currentenv.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib does not exist.
```

Other responses on SO suggest that the environment variable isn't created but If I run the following:

```
echo $TOMCAT_HOME
```

it returns:

```
/usr/local/tomcat7
```

So I know that the variable exists and is set.

This is the build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- #######################################################################
                        B u i l d   S c r i p t
####################################################################### -->

<project name="EES" default="war">
        <description> EES </description>
        <property environment="currentenv" />
        <property name="tomcat.home" location="${currentenv.TOMCAT_HOME}"/>
        <property file="build.${currentenv.ANT_HOST_NAME}" />
        <property name="webapp.path" value="build"/>

<!-- #######################################################################
                T a r g e t : I n i t
####################################################################### -->

  <target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <echo>Build of ${ant.project.name} started at ${TSTAMP} on ${TODAY}</echo>
  </target>


<!-- #######################################################################
                T a r g e t : D e f a u l t
####################################################################### -->

        <target name="war" depends="init, clean, compile,compilejsp,copywebroot" description="Bundle up everything">
        <!-- target name="war" depends="init, clean,compile,copywebroot" description="Bundle up everything" -->
                <echo>Packaging ${ant.project.name}</echo>
                <jar destfile="EES.war" basedir="${webapp.path}"/>
                <echo>Finished packaging ${ant.project.name}</echo>
        </target>

<!-- #######################################################################
                T a r g e t : C o p y w e b r o o t
####################################################################### -->

        <target name="copywebroot">
                <copy todir="${webapp.path}" >
                        <fileset dir="WebRoot">
                               <include name="**"/>
                        </fileset>
                </copy>
        </target>

<!-- #######################################################################
                T a r g e t : j s p c
####################################################################### -->
        <target name="jspc">

                <taskdef classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC" name="jasper2" >
                        <classpath id="jspc.classpath">
                                <pathelement location="${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar"/>
                                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/bin">
                                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
                                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
                                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${ant.home}/lib">
                                        <include name="ant.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                        </classpath>
                </taskdef>
                <mkdir dir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/src"/>
<!--            <jasper2 verbose="255"
                     validateXml="false"
                     uriroot="${webapp.path}"
                     webXmlFragment="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml"
                     outputDir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/src" /> -->
                 <java classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC"
                          classpathref="jspc.classpath"
                          fork="true" failonerror="true">
                        <arg line="-v -d ${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/src -webapp ${webapp.path}"/>
                    </java>

        </target>
        <target name="compilejsp" depends="jspc">
                <mkdir dir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
                <mkdir dir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/lib"/>

                <javac destdir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"
                        optimize="off"
                        debug="on" failonerror="false"
                        srcdir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/src"
                        excludes="**/*.smap">
                        <classpath>
                                <pathelement location="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
                                <fileset dir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/lib">
                                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                                <pathelement location="${tomcat.home}/lib"/>
                                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
                                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/bin">
                                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                        </classpath>
                        <include name="**" />
                        <exclude name="tags/**" />
                </javac>
        </target>

<!-- #######################################################################
                T a r g e t : C o m p i l e
####################################################################### -->

        <target name="compile">
                <echo>Compiling ${ant.project.name}</echo>
                <mkdir dir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
                <javac includeAntRuntime="false" srcdir="src"
                                debug="on"
                                destdir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes">
                        <!--destdir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes">-->
                        <classpath>
                                <fileset dir="WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib">
                                        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
                                        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                                </fileset>
                        </classpath>
                </javac>
                <copy file="src/in.xls"
                          tofile="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/ees/action/in.xls">

                </copy>
        <copy todir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <include name="**"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

                         <echo>Finished compiling ${ant.project.name}</echo>
        </target>



        <!-- =================================
          target: deploy
         ================================= -->
    <target name="deploy" depends="war" description="--> deploys the war file locally">
        <copy todir="${tomcat.home}/webapps"  file="EES.war"/>
    </target>

        <target name="remotedeploy" depends="war">
                <scp keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa" passphrase="" file="EES.war"  remoteTodir="x@y.com.com:" verbose="true"/>
                <sshexec keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa" host="x.y.com" username="xxx"  command="/home/xxx/deployees"/>
        </target>

<!-- #######################################################################
                T a r g e t : C l e a n
####################################################################### -->
        <target name="clean">
                <echo>Cleaning ${ant.project.name}</echo>
                <delete dir="${webapp.path}" >
                </delete>
        </target>
</project>
```

Any advice on how to fix?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `build.xml`? `$TOMCAT_HOME` is set properly, no doubt, but the FAILED message indicates that ant script is trying to search the TOMCAT home inside your `/home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES` folder which indicates some configuration issue. Most probably, you will have to change some configuration so as to point it to the actual TOMCAT folder.

Comment: @PrahladYeri I have added to the original question above.

Comment: I'm not experienced with Centos 6. Are you launching the Ant script manually? If so, please post the exact command line. If not, how is it launched? Through some console manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that Ant does not "see" `TOMCAT_HOME` because the system process in which Ant has been called has not that variable defined on it.

Ensure you are calling Ant from the same system user that has a `TOMCAT_HOME` variable in its profile, and also that the environment variables are preserved when launching Ant.

Comment: You are right. I added TOMCAT_HOME to env_keep in /etc/sudoers and then when I ran sudo ant it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but I changed this line in the build.xml

```
<fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
```

to point to the location of tomcat:

```
<fileset dir="/usr/local/tomcat7/lib">
```

And that did the trick.

Should the line have read something like:

```
<fileset dir="${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib">
```

to match the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have temporarily solved the build issue by assigning the hard-coded value  `dir="/usr/local/tomcat7/lib"`, but that is not a permanent fix. If you format your machine and the path changes, or if you share this code with someone who might have a different `tomcat` installation path, it will be a problem. The real culprit in your `ant` script is this line of code:

```
<property name="tomcat.home" location="${currentenv.TOMCAT_HOME}"/>
```

You see, the `location` attribute is used in `ant` properties if you want to specify a [relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628457/what-s-the-difference-between-ants-property-value-and-property-location). You have specified `location` attribute so ant build is searching for `tomcat` installation relative to your current path desperately (and thus fails):

```
/home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/${currentenv.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib
```

The solution here is to specify a `value` attribute instead of `location` since your `$TOMCAT_HOME` refers to an absolute path in `/usr/local`:

```
<property name="tomcat.home" value="${currentenv.TOMCAT_HOME}"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as the build now fails further down. I now get:  BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/build.xml:51: /home/ec2-user/twv/trunk/EES/${currentenv.TOMCAT_HOME}/bin does not exist. which is the jspc section.

Comment: Is that really the reason why you downvoted my answer! In any case, I still think the issue is with making incorrect use of `location` in place of `value` in your ant script. For instance, there is a line `<pathelement location="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"/>` which needs to be changed as well. If you don't want to bother then just leave the hard-coded as it is. As long as it works, its fine.

Comment: Firstly I didn't down vote your answer. Don't know who did but it wasn't me. Secondly changing location to name didn't work for me but hard coding did and that's all I need right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add my 0.02$, I've experienced this issue because I had a typo in the var names passed to `mkdir`, and consequently when `mkdir` was executed then as there was no var to expand then it just created a dir matching the variable name.